# how to send email to the case related contacts after created record in case object where case priority(medium,High,low)

Tags: email, email2case

**We have condition:**

1. If case priority will be Low than need to send email case related contact after 30 minutes.
2. If case priority will be Medium than need to send email case related contact after 1 hour.
3. If case priority will be High than need to send email case related contact after 4 hours.

Please anyone have idea share with us.

Answer (score 1):

Please create one formula field which will store time at which email should be fired. formula will look like `IF(IsPickVal(Priority,'High'),CreatedDate + (4 * 60)/1440, IF(IsPickVal(Priority,'medium'),CreatedDate + (1 * 60)/1440, IF(IsPickVal(Priority,'medium'),CreatedDate + (0.5 * 60)/1440, CreatedDate)))`

Then create a time dependent workflow which will fire email alert after 0 hours of this formula field created.

Comment: Hi Martin
can you tell me  what time i have to select in workflow time trigger

Comment: 0 days after formula field that you have created in above step.

Comment: Hi Rishi 
workflow time trigger is not hitting after 30 mint 1 hour and and 4 hour .Ihave already selected on time trigger is 0 Days .